# adjacent sibling selector missing first element

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Given this html:

```
<div class="rating-system book-rating-27" title="Average rating: out of 5 (0 ratings)">
<a class="rating-star star-27 star-27-1 rating-star-edit" href="#" onclick="setStarRating(27, 1);return false;"><img src="images/star_empty.png"></a>
<a class="rating-star star-27 star-27-2 rating-star-edit" href="#" onclick="setStarRating(27, 2);return false;"><img src="images/star_empty.png"></a>
<a class="rating-star star-27 star-27-3 rating-star-edit" href="#" onclick="setStarRating(27, 3);return false;"><img src="images/star_empty.png"></a>
<a class="rating-star star-27 star-27-4 rating-star-edit" href="#" onclick="setStarRating(27, 4);return false;"><img src="images/star_empty.png"></a>
<a class="rating-star star-27 star-27-5 rating-star-edit" href="#" onclick="setStarRating(27, 5);return false;"><img src="images/star_empty.png"></a>
<input id="hidden_book_rating_27" name="book_rating" type="hidden" value="0"><br>
</div>
```

If I use jquery to find the elements of class "rating-star-edit", it returns all 5 as expected:

[image]

Then again if I select the elements of class "star-27" it works fine, returning all 5 of those (and a few different ones which are non-editing ones):

[image]

However, if I use an adjacent sibling selector to get just those which are both class "star-27" and "rating-star-edit", for some reason it skips the first one and returns only 4:

[image]

Can anyone see where I am going wrong? Is that not the correct way to use the adjacent sibling selector, or have I made an error somewhere with my HTML?

Cheers.

Comment: Are you looking for elements that have both classes? If so, it should be `.star-27.rating-star-edit`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_selectors) `.A + .B` won't give you a collection of elements having both `.A` and `.B`.

It represents all the `.B`s that immediately follow `.A`s

CSS level 2 Spec states:

> **[5.7 Adjacent sibling selectors](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/selector.html#adjacent-selectors)**
>
> djacent sibling selectors have the following syntax: `E1 + E2`, where **`E2`
>   is the subject** of the selector. The selector matches if `E1` and `E2`
>   share the same parent in the document tree and `E1` immediately precedes
>   `E2`, ignoring non-element nodes (such as text nodes and comments).

Hence the first element won't be matched and the result would be 4 elements.

In order to select the elements having both `.A` and `.B` classes, you should use `.A.B` instead.
In your case: `.star-27.rating-star-edit`.

Answer (score 0):

It returns only 4 because the first `star-27` is not an adjacent sibiling of any element...

The `sel1 + sel2` selector, targets every element matching `sel2` that directly follows another element matching `sel1`.

Answer (score 0):

There's nothing wrong. Its correct to get 4 elements because adjacent means next siblings. What happens is that you ask for the first occurrency of '.star-27' who has a sibling to had a class '.rating-star-edit' and find the first one and write the next sibling. Then go on for the other four elements and so. If you want all of them, you should take the '+' out.